# creating a dynamic array with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

i got a problem with my php script. My experience in php is not so good, so it would be great if you could help me :)

I got a foreach construct:

foreach ($column as $key => $value)
{

}

What i now want is creating a multidimensional associative array in this foreach constuct. The $key value will be used to generate the array; so at the end the array should look like this:

```
$queries = array(
                        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/[here_should_be_the_$key_value]?fields=first_name'),
                        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/[here_should_be_the_$key_value]?fields=first_name'),
                        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/[here_should_be_the_$key_value]?fields=first_name'),
                        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/[here_should_be_the_$key_value]?fields=first_name'),
                        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/[here_should_be_the_$key_value]?fields=first_name')

the length depends
```

Do you have any hints for me? I thank you for reading my thread.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, are you trying to do something like that?

```
foreach($column as $key => $value) {
    $query[] = array('method' => 'GET',
                     'relative_url' => $key . '?fields=first_name');
}
print_r($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if you're asking this. hope this helps.

```
$arr= array();

    foreach($column as $key => $value)
    {
     $arr[] = array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => $key."?fields=".$value); // here maybe a happy little value :)
    }
    $queries = array();
    $queries[] = $arr;
    print_r($queries);
```